# DismissmodalViewController donot remove the modal View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have been figuring out this since yesterday but have not got that correct yet.
I have added the modalviewcontroller for my loading view controller on top of my tab bar controller and it works fine. 
Added the code in app Delegate:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
   [navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
   [window addSubview:rootController.view]; 
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
   LoadingViewController *lvc = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingView" bundle:nil]; 
    // Delegate added here
   lvc.loadingDelegate = self;
   [rootController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES]; 
   [self URL]; 
   [lvc release]; 
   return TRUE; 
}
```

Now I do my parsing and when its done I call the following code in different view name XMLParsingView.m where the parsing got over.

```
- (void)handleLoadedApps
 {
 LoadingViewController *loading = [[[LoadingViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 //delegating to let the load view controller know to dimiss itself by defining  disappear method in protocol
 [loading.loadingDelegate disappear];
 }
```

and in loading view controller I have method which calls dismissModalViewControlAnimated:

```
 -(void)disappear{
[activity stopAnimating];
[activity removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromSuperview];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But for some reason it will never remove the view and not load it back to my tab bar controller.
Really need help here if any one have come across such issues.

Sagos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you seem to create, without a nib, a **new** LoadingViewController and immediately go and dismiss it. In your app delegate you create your first loadingViewController with a nib, present it modally on rootController and then release it. Since you want to dismiss it outside your app delegate you have

3 choices, (hardest to fastest and most sane)

a) Key-Value-Observing on a property of XMLParsingView from LoadingViewController to remove itself when the task finishes.

b) Use delegation to inform the LoadingViewController when the task finishes to dismiss itself.

c) Fetch your rootController from your [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate], which means you must expose rootController as a property or through a method, and make rootController dismiss your modal.

Comment: @tsakoyan : I have edited my answer above with option b of yours. But still it does not help me to remove the modal view controller. Am I doing it correctly btw ?

Comment: LoadingViewController *loading comes out of nowhere, it shouldn't be used, when I meant delegating it was smth like xmlParsingViewInstance.loadingDelegate = lvc; inside your app delegate ... then inside the XMLParsingView - (void)disappear {[self.loadingDelegate didFinishTask];}, however I recommend (c) myapp_delegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [appDel.rootController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Thanks bro !!! U r awesome man !!! I was banging my head for past 6 hours now !!!! The issue was I didnt use option C and was giving me errors all this while. myapp_delegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [appDel.rootController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @tsakoyan: One last query: When I write the above code, modalviewcontroller appears after the tab bar is loaded meaning we can make out that it is coming from below as a different view. How to avoid that by showing it immediatey after splash screen and then load the tab bar ?

Comment: make lvc a class variable, expose it as a property so you can access it/release it later: lvc = [[Loading... alloc] ...]; [window addSubview:lvc.view]; [window insertSubview:rootController.view atIndex:0]; and then at wherever the task finishes [appDel.lvc.view removeFromSuperview]; appDel.lvc = nil;

Comment: so should I use [self.rootController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES]; or remove it with addSubview....

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` on the `rootViewController`, not the loading view controller.

Comment: Called -(void) disappear{ [self.loadingController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];} But still it will not remove it.

Comment: You don't need to call it on the rootViewController.  It should work by calling it on the viewcontroller itself.

Comment: Jamie: It is not working as I have written in my main question on the above code. Do you think I am mising any thing ?

Comment: @Jamie Technically it works but you should call it on the parent: "The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal view controller it presented using the presentModalViewController:animated: method."

Comment: I have tried removing the modal view through the parent view controller which is my tab bar controller and also through the loading view controller but still cannot get the modal view controller removed. Can you really help me what are the issues I should look for more?